# Xamarin Forms MainActivity OnCreate LoadApplication System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, splash-screen

I am using VS2015 with Xamarin to create a multi-platform project that can show a splashscreen and then load a webpage in a webview. Here is my project structure. I am using a PCL project type as below:

[image]

*TheApp (Portable)*

```
-WebPageHoster.Xaml     //Contains a WebView control
   -WebPageHoster.Xaml.cs  //sets the WebView controls source property to load a webpage
   -App.Xaml
   -App.Xaml.cs
```

*TheApp.Droid*

```xml
/Resources/drawable/splashlogo.png
/Resources/drawable/icon3.png
/Resources/values/Styles.xml
-MainActivity.cs
-SplashActivity.cs
```

*TheApp.iOS*

*TheApp.WindowsPhone(Windows Phone 8.1)*

This is the code in the `Styles.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Splash" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashlogo</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

*SplashActivity.cs*

```cs
[Activity(MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true, Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash", Icon = "@drawable/icon3")]
public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        StartActivity(intent);
        Finish();
    }
}
```

*MainActivity.cs*

```cs
[Activity(Label = "Splash App",  ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());  // << Problem here
    }
```

The `LoadApplication` method call in the `OnCreate` method above loads the app constructor of the App.Xaml.cs class which runs the following code

public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new WebPageHoster() { Title = "Load Web-Page" });
    }

This shows the splash screen and after setting the WebView's url reaches back to the OnCreate method and gives this error

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

I am unable to find what is causing this error. Here is the Android Manifest file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="TheApp.TheApp" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="1">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon3" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" android:label="Splash Web Host"></application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: share the source please. you shouldn't paste too much code in the question.

Comment: changed from FormsApplicationActivity to FormsAppCompatActivity and got a new problem. Code uploaded to dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/s/p2snfvsyhhwopgn/STM-full.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I tested your source code and your `MainActivity` derives from `FormsAppCompatActivity`.
In that case you must provide a theme that uses `AppCompat`.

To solve that, I added an `AppCompat` Theme to your styles:

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

And then used it on your `MainActivity`:

```cs
[Activity(Label = "Southern Travel", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
```

Comment: Thank you. Thank you. Was going crazy with this. Where can I get real documentation around Xamarin Forms? It seems like wherever I look its something specific to a particular target platform. Even this official documentation[https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/SplashScreen/] on the Xamarin site doesn't do this example in the PCL form:

Comment: @user20358, setting a SpalshScreen is different between iOS and Android, this post might help for Android https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/91914/#Comment_91914

Comment: There is here a good tutorial on this for android and iOS: http://codeworks.it/blog/?p=294

Comment: Hi..My code is just as you have said. But still it shows null pointer exception on this line( LoadApplication(new App());  ) in mainActivity.cs.

Comment: @AadhilAhmed you should read the full stackstrace and try to understand.

Comment: The problem was with packages.config file which I found later.Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean?