# xamarin forms appcompat nullreference exception

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-appcompat

I'm getting a NullReferenceException at this line:

LoadApplication(new App());

In my main activity.
What I was working on was adding a Compat Theme in order to get [this](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-forms-tab-badge) badge plugin working, following [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/material-theme/) and [this](https://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-material-design-v7-appcompat/) blog post.

```
[Activity(Label = "ServiceApp.Droid", 
MainLauncher = true,
ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]

public class MainActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity {
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        FormsAppCompatActivity.ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
        FormsAppCompatActivity.TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        [...]
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    } 
    [...]
}
```

Resources looking like this:
Resources/values/color.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="primary">#FFDD00</color>
  <color name="primaryDark">#FFDD00</color>
  <color name="primaryLight">#FFECB3</color>
  <color name="accent">#9E9E9E</color>
  <color name="primaryText">#212121</color>
  <color name="secondaryText">#757575</color>
  <color name="window_background">#FFFFFF</color>
  <color name="icons">#212121</color>
  <color name="divider">#BDBDBD</color>
</resources>
```

Resources/values/styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Resources/values-v21/styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">

    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Also
Resources/layout/Tabbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

And
Resources/layout/Toolbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
```

Am I missing something about the themes? Or is there a way to get more info about the exception? (Did check the android traces.txt which didn't seem helpful)
I followed it by stepping through the LoadApplication(new App()); and it seemed it crashed on the very last step but I have no idea what actually is null to cause the issue.

Comment: Have you provided your Application class that is your app.xaml a mainpage???

Comment: Yes I do have a MainPage. I should note that the app did work before trying to move to AppCompat.

Comment: So the Problem started after moving to appcompact?

Comment: Yes, the error didnt occur before.

Comment: Well when it crashes what does it say inflation error ? or what ?

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the problem, check this post:
[Xamarin Forms MainActivity OnCreate LoadApplication System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38025447/xamarin-forms-mainactivity-oncreate-loadapplication-system-nullreferenceexceptio)

In General, you are missing the theme in your activity definition

```
[Activity(Label = "ServiceApp.Droid", 
Theme = "@style/MyTheme",
MainLauncher = true,
ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
```